# Open Source Spell Check for javascript Typo.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As I try to use the typo.js spell checker in my file. But it's throw some error's I can't find the solutions. I just followed the Typo.js Documentation Here is the document link.
https://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js/
Kindly check the below issue and help me to reach out this issue

[Here is the console issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EEYa.png)

Here is the used code

**JS**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Typo.js Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="typo/typo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dictionary = new Typo("en_US", false, false, { dictionaryPath: "typo/dictionaries" });

        // function load() {
        //     $('#loading-progress').append('Loading affix data...').append($('<br />'));

        //     $.get('typo/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.aff', function (affData) {
        //         $('#loading-progress').append('Loading English dictionary (this takes a few seconds)...').append($('<br />'));

        //         $.get('typo/dictionaries/en_US/en_US.dic', function (wordsData) {
        //             $('#loading-progress').append('Initializing Typo...');

        //             dictionary = new Typo("en_US", affData, wordsData);

        //             checkWord('mispelled');
        //         });
        //     });
        // }

        checkWord('mispelled');

        function checkWord(word) {
            var wordForm = $('#word-form');
            wordForm.hide();

            var resultsContainer = $('#results');
            resultsContainer.html('');

            resultsContainer.append($('<p>').text("Is '" + word + "' spelled correctly?"));

            var is_spelled_correctly = dictionary.check(word);

            resultsContainer.append($('<p>').append($('<code>').text(is_spelled_correctly ? 'yes' : 'no')));

            if (!is_spelled_correctly) {
                resultsContainer.append($('<p>').text("Finding spelling suggestions for '" + word + "'..."));

                var array_of_suggestions = dictionary.suggest(word);

                resultsContainer.append($('<p>').append($('<code>').text(array_of_suggestions.join(', '))));
            }

            wordForm.show();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Typo.js Demo</h1>
    <p>This page is an example of how you could use <a href="http://github.com/cfinke/Typo.js">Typo.js</a> in a webpage
        if you need spellchecking beyond what the OS provides.</p>
    <p id="loading-progress"></p>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <form method="GET" action="" onsubmit="checkWord( document.getElementById( 'word' ).value ); return false;"
        id="word-form" style="display: none;">
        <p>Try another word:</p>
        <input type="text" id="word" value="mispelled" />
        <input type="submit" value="Spellcheck" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure why you have `file://` set as path. you should atleast be running a *virtual server - xampp/wampp* or something similair, so you can request the file through localhost, then ajax should work and the cors error should be gone

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run an http request on a filesystem. You need a development web server to work with this library to host your dictionary or use a cloud based service using someone else's server. Any spell check will require a server to host the dictionary. There are free and integrated options with many IDE's such as Visual Studio Community or Visual Studio Code. As well as many other web servers including many good free options. Also XmlHttpRequest is deprecated but still works, I'm still using it.